# Setting Contrasts for ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I've been attempting to perform an ANOVA in [r](/questions/tagged/r) recently on the attached data frame.
My design is a 3×5 within-subjects design.
There are 3 visual conditions under `Circle1` and 5 audio under `Beep1`.

Does anyone have any idea how I should set the contrasts? This is something I'm unfamiliar with as I'm making the transition from point-and-click stats in [spss](/questions/tagged/spss) to coded in R.
Thanks for your time.

[CSV data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjylihccmlvkkwa/Contrast_Data_ANOVA.csv)